# Positioning a div circle on the center of four col-md-6 bootstrap div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve a layout as shown in the figure below:
[image]

I have 4 col-md-6 dive with a background image (and size cover), i want to put on top of the center of them a circle with a text (completely implemented in CSS).

I want to keep the design responsive so I was wondering which is the best way of dealing with absolute and relative positioning and responsiveness?

Answer (score 1):

you can make your `row` div `position: relative`
create a `circle` div that is `position: absolute` within the row (next to your `col-md-6` divs) and center the the circle div within the row using `top, left` and negative `margin`s

something like:

```css
.container {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}

.row-with-medallion {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.row-with-medallion .quadrant {
    color: #027BC4;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 45px 0;
    background: white;
}
.the-medallion {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(2, 123, 196, 1);
    color: #B8BFC5;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-with-medallion">
        <div class="col-md-6 quadrant">col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 quadrant">col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 quadrant">col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 quadrant">col-md-6</div>
        <div class="the-medallion">???</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it's what I was looking for. But I tried to implement myself on my project and it's not working. Basically it seems that is ignoring the top: 50% of the css. The parent position is relative and the children is absolute do you have any idea? Here part of the code: http://pastebin.com/wnBiPsFz